# ArrayController's "arrangedContent" not always updated when "sortAscending" is set

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to set up dynamic sorting in my Ember.ArrayController subclass using one HTML select tag as follows:

```
App.ListController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
    sortOptions: [{id: 0, text: 'Price High-Low', sortBy: 'pricing', sortAsc: false},
              {id: 1, text: 'Price Low-High', sortBy: 'pricing', sortAsc: true},
              {id: 2, text: 'Name Ascending', sortBy: 'name', sortAsc: true},
              {id: 3, text: 'Name Descending', sortBy: 'name', sortAsc: false}]
    currentSortOptionId: 0

    sortBy: (->
        this.get('sortOptions')[this.get('currentSortOptionId')].sortBy
    ).property('currentSortOptionId')

    # Override
    sortProperties: (->
        [this.get('sortBy')]
    ).property('sortBy')

    # Override
    sortAscending: (->
        this.get('sortOptions')[this.get('currentSortOptionId')].sortAsc
    ).property('currentSortOptionId')
```

In my template, I've got:

```
Sort by {{view Ember.Select content=sortOptions
                                    optionValuePath="content.id"
                                    optionLabelPath="content.text"
                                    value=currentSortOptionId}}

{{#each listing in controller.arrangeContent}}
    ...
{{/each}}
```

Changing the selector works most of the time, and *always* works in switching the sort property. However, the sort direction (via "sortAscending") property gets confused, and seems to sometimes get one action behind (ie. uses the previously selected value for "sortAscending").

What could be going on here?

EDIT: Here's a JSFiddle of an isolated example: http://jsfiddle.net/s9AFr/3/

If you change the sort selector a few times, you can convince yourself that it's sorting incorrectly *some of the time*, especially when it comes to the ascending/descending feature of the sort. The sort seems to "lag" behind the user's choice.

Comment: Can you throw this into a JSBin / fiddle? See [here] for a template. Also, I assume `controller.arrangeContent` is a typo and you meant **arrangedContent**

Comment: Yes yes, arrangedContent is what I meant, and that's what I'm using in the app. Your template link didn't seem to make it through in your comment

Comment: @SherwinYu, just added a JSFiddle!

Comment: I think this is due to a bug unfortunately. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I think this is due to a [bug](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/3422).

### Why it happens

Basically what happens is right now Ember doesn't expect both sortProperties and sortAscending to change at the same time. In the SortableMixin's `sortAscendingWillChange` observer, we keep track of the old value for `sortAscending` (storing it in `_lastSortAscending`), and then, in the after observer, if  `sortAscending` did indeed, they simply [flip the `arrangedContent` array](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/3726c072f7f9695a3bcb4a26dd1330ef9cb115cd/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/sortable.js?source=c#L182):

```
sortAscendingDidChange: Ember.observer('sortAscending', function() {
  if (get(this, 'sortAscending') !== this._lastSortAscending) {
    var arrangedContent = get(this, 'arrangedContent');
    arrangedContent.reverseObjects();
  }
}),
```

The problem arises when you set `sortAscending` and `sortProperties` at the same time, as the `sortAscendingWillChange` before observer fires, keeping rack of the OLD sortAscending property, then because `sortProperties` changed, the array will get re-sorted, using the NEW value of `sortAscending` (so at this point, everything is sorted as you expect).... but then finally the `sortAscendingDidChange` observer fires, sees that sortAscending is different, so it flips the entire array again.

### EDIT: Work around ([JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9AFr/4/))

Given the cause of this bug, I think the workaround is to make sure `sortAscending` and `sortProperties` don't change simultaneously.

So instead of making `sortAscending` a computed property, we can set it in an observer that observes `currentSortOptionId`, taking care to set it in the next run loop (so we use `Ember.run.later`). This way, the `sortProperties` computed property will change first, the content will get sorted, and then the `sortAscending` property will be set afterward.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and work-around. Seems to do the trick. Now, I guess I just have to wait for the bug to be fixed! With this work-around, it looks like the arrangeContent is calculated twice; do you see any way around that?

Comment: @elsurudo, I don't see any easy way around it unfortunately. The PR seems to be in active development so hopefully this will be fixed soon.